# Subreport is not displayed

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I started working with subreports in JapserReports. At the beginning I would like to do something very simple.
This is xml code of my subreport:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Rb50dane" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <field name="column01" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="22" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="208" y="0" width="257" height="22"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="3.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="3.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="3.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="3.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="3.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{column01}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

And this is part of my main report code:

```
<detail>
        <band height="22" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="208" y="0" width="257" height="22"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\mg\\Jasper\\Rb50data.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
```

As you can see I do not use any parameter in my subreport. Unfortunately, in iReport after compiling my main report, subreport is not displayed, but when I try to run my subreport separately it works.

In my test I use empty data source. I just want to see the column with null value to find out whether the subreport works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try adding something in the dataSourceExpression of the parent report. Maybe send the whole data source by using *

Comment: I 've added: new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource(1) and it works